# can anyone determine why the Jquery ui tabs events are not firing in the below code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

in the below code none of the alerts are getting called?

```
<head>
<script src='../../Scripts/jquery/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../content/jquery-tabs/jquery.tabs.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen">
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-tabs/jquery.history_remote.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-tabs/jquery.tabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {

            // Objects available in the function context:
            alert(ui.tab);     // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
            alert(ui.panel);   // element, that contains the selected/clicked tab contents
            alert(ui.index);   // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
        });
    });


</script> 

</head>
<body>

<h2>
    TestTabs</h2>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>1 Info</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>2 Info</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>3 Info</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-4"><span>4 Info</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <h2>TestTabs</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
        <h2>TestTabs</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-3">
        <h2>TestTabs</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-4">
        <h2>TestTabs</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It works for me](http://jsbin.com/oxivi).

Make sure that you're using the current version of jQuery UI.

Do you get any script errors?

Comment: how would i know if i get a script error.  also, i tried debugging through firebug but i never get the callback.  do i need jquery-ui.js as well as jquery.tabs.js.  i thought that jquery.tabs.js was all that was needed

Comment: No, you need both `jquery-ui.js` and your tabs file, but you should really use the compressed bundle the site creates for you which wraps both into one file.

Comment: basically started from scratch as Doug mentioned as well as somehow it s working now . . think it was due to the missing jquery-ui files

Comment: actually, i see an issue with your example,  i dont see #fragment- after you click on each tab.. do you know why this disappeared ??

Answer (score 2):

The code looks correct, which means most likely it is one of two things:

1. Another JS error on the page
2. You have not correctly included the UI library + tabs

My guess is #2, so you should double check that it is working. For kicks, go back to the http://jqueryui.com/download page, click "deselect all components" and then click on "Tabs" to select only `core` and `tabs`. Then choose "no theme" then download. Use that `js` file in place of your `tabs.min.js` file and see if it works then.

Last thing to check, make sure the version of jQuery + jQuery UI you are using match. For jQuery 1.3+, use jQuery UI 1.7.2. For jQuery 1.2.6, use jQuery UI 1.6